# How to create a custom annotation for both classes and methods?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I have to create a custom Logged annotation that can be added to both classes and methods. This is what I've done so far but only works for methods...

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Logger {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you intended to add the `ElementType.TYPE` to the @Target

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
```